# Ridiculously high costs under "No Instance Type" in aws cost explorer

Tags: amazon-web-services, billing, aws-billing, aws-cost-explorer

Over 75% of monthly costs are under "No Instance Type", I've calculated the total costs of unallocated elastic IPs, volumes and snapshots, and the sum doesnt even come close. Any pointers on how to break this down further?[image: Here's the breakdown]

Further, the cost explorer marks "no instance type" with "***" which expands to `This category includes costs (e.g., data transfer in/out) that are not directly attributable to a specific Instance  Type.` in the legend.

Comment: Can you show us some details? By the way, this question will probably get closed because StackOverflow is a site for asking Programming Q&A. You might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, thanks. I've posted there too. Updated my question.

Comment: Filter by instance type, selecting "No instance type" and group by "Usage Type".